# CMake how to handle dpendencies to files retrieved via externalProject_add

Tags: git, cmake, glfw

I am using the `externalProject_add` command to retrive the whole glfm project directly from github. As part of this checkout two files will be retrieved through git. These two files (glad.c and glad.h) will be needed to be added as source dependency for my project.

Unfortunatly CMake complies during generation that these files are missing, which is correct because the will be download during build later.

Error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:79 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

H:/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/BuildCMakeExternalOpenGL/glfw -prefix/src/glfw/deps/glad/glad.h

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
.hxx .in .txx


CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: CMakeExternalTemplate
Generating done
```

How can I solve this?

My CMake File:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(CMakeExternalTemplate)

include(ExternalProject)

set(EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/libs)

#CMakeExternalTemplate
# -- Vars
set(CMakeExternalTemplate_SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
set(CMakeExternalTemplate_INCLUDE_DIRS)

# -- GLM
set(glm_INSTALL_DIR ${EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR}/glm)
externalProject_add(glm
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/g-truc/glm.git
    GIT_TAG 0.9.8.1
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${glm_INSTALL_DIR}")
ExternalProject_Get_Property(glm source_dir)
set(GLM_SRC_DIR ${source_dir})

#GLFW
# -- Vars
set(glfw_INSTALL_DIR ${EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR}/glfw)
set(glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS ${glfw_INSTALL_DIR}/include)

externalProject_add(glfw
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
    GIT_TAG 3.2.1
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${glfw_INSTALL_DIR}")

ExternalProject_Get_Property(glfw source_dir)
set(GLFW_SRC_DIR ${source_dir})

#Glad
set(GLAD "${GLFW_SRC_DIR}/deps/glad/glad.h"
         "${GLFW_SRC_DIR}/deps/glad.c")

include_directories(${GLM_SRC_DIR})
include_directories(${glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLFW_SRC_DIR}/deps )

# -- -- CMakeExternalTemplate
include_directories(${CMakeExternalTemplate_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# -- Compile
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMakeExternalTemplate_SOURCE_FILES} ${GLAD})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External project is not meant to be used that way. It creates compilation targets.

It will download these libraries and build them so it is not needed to include the source files of them.

What you should do is link against the libraries they create (see `target_link_library` and `link_directories`.) If you only need the result of the `glad.c` you probably could link against the object file of it.

You also need to add a manual dependency though so you make sure the download and compilation of these libraries get done before

```
add_dependency(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw glm)
```

---

If for some reason you need the source files to be there explicitly you cannot use `External_project`. You would have to do it manually during cmake configuration with `execute_process(git clone ... )` and the other commands you need.

Comment: The two needed files are dependencies from glfw. Unfortunately I have to use the exact same version as glfw to be link compatible. You might be right to need to use `execute_process`, but I still hope there is an easier way.

Comment: @BerndL. afaik there are no frameworks for this. Can you not just link in the resulting object file in your binary? I mean the header should never be needed. You can just add a "include" in one of your files and it gets compiled. If you wanna go "hacky" you could also just include the C file in the source code but I think object linking would be cleaner

Comment: The problem is, that I really have to add glad.c to my executable to be able to link. But if this glad.c file will be retrieved during the first build it is to late.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is CMake superbuild approach. Superbuild will set things up so that you have two nested layers of CMake executing - first layer will pull down external projects, optionally compile them if needed.

And then, it will call itself as another externalproject, pass along downloaded external directories and then you can use these in your project definitions as you wish. It is a bit cumbersome, and still does not actually neatly auto-populate everything in IDE for you.

Search github/google for cmake superbuild templates and try them out - it's not ideal, but you do get consistent builds in development and CI environments.